# Gps accuracy in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

In android native we can identify the accuracy of gps location obtained using

```
locationProvider.getAccuracy()
```

Ref: [LocationProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationProvider.html#getAccuracy%28%29)

Are there similar methods in phonegap to identify the accuracy of GPS location obtained by the `geolocation.watchPosition` and `geolocation.getCurrentPosition` Methodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The returned position object holds the accurracy:

```
var onSuccess = function(position) {
alert('Latitude: '          + position.coords.latitude          + '\n' +
      'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude         + '\n' +
      'Altitude: '          + position.coords.altitude          + '\n' +
      'Accuracy: '          + position.coords.accuracy          + '\n' +
      'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy  + '\n' +
      'Heading: '           + position.coords.heading           + '\n' +
      'Speed: '             + position.coords.speed             + '\n' +
      'Timestamp: '         + new Date(position.timestamp)      + '\n');
```

};

Answer (score 1):

You can use watchPosition instead of getCurrentPosition. Then you your 
onSuccess function will be triggered everytime there is a change in 
the location(when it is more accurate). In this function you can check 
the accuracy and then stop the gps ensor with clearWatch

courtesy ([Wilin](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/Cg-BidKgbFQ) )